# Linux to windows execute commands remotely

Tags: windows, ssh

I have to zip files on a remote windows machine.
So I first ssh to the windows machine

```
ssh my_user@my_host "cd /d D:\MyFolder"
```

And the above command works.

However if I try to run any command after that it fails.

So if I do something like

```
ssh my_user@my_host "cd /d D:\MyFolder; dir"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
ssh my_user@my_host <<EOF
cd /d D:\MyFolder
dir
EOF
```

The second `EOF` should be alone on the line and start from the begin